# If $2s=a+b+c$, show that $(s-a)^3+(s-b)^3+(s-c)^3+3abc=s^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $2s=a+b+c$, show that $(s-a)^3+(s-b)^3+(s-c)^3+3abc=s^3$

$(s-a)^3 = s^3-3s^2a+3sa^2-a^3 \\ (s-b)^3 = s^3-3s^2b+3sb^2-b^3 \\ (s-c)^3 = s^3-3s^2c+3sc^2-c^3$

$\Rightarrow 3s^3 -3as^2+3a^2s-3bs^2+3b^2s-3cs^2+3c^2s-a^3-b^3-c^3+3abc=s^3 \\ \Rightarrow 2s^3 -3as^2+3a^2s-3bs^2+3b^2s-3cs^2+3c^2s=a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$

Note that $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc = (a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ac)$

$2s^3 -3as^2+3a^2s-3bs^2+3b^2s-3cs^2+3c^2s \Rightarrow 2s^3-3s(as+a^2-bs+b^2-cs+c^2)$

Now I'm stuck because I can't simplify any further. Obviously there is a way but I can't see it. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think you are going the wrong way. You want to show that the LHS is equal to RHS. So simplify and expand the LHS. You should not touch the RHS. You may eventually get something like $a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ which you can write out as $(a+b+c)^2 - (2ab + 2bc + 2ac)$. make similar simplifications and you will eventually get there.

Comment: You want to prove $(-a+b+c)^3 + (a-b+c)^3 + (a+b-c)^3 + 24abc = (a+b+c)^3$. Since the terms in $a^3$ cancel out, that leaves a quadratic identity in $a$, so it's enough to verify it for $3$ values of $a$.

Comment: what have you right now you can literally take $s$ out of both sides and then you are only left with quadratic terms. Also, group like same groups of $s$ together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some easier ways than direct calculations. Possible approach: First, reduce to the form that @dxiv: indicated, to make it more transparent. Now, look at

$$(a+b-c)^3 + (b+c-a)^3 + (c+a-b)^3 - (a+b+c)^3$$

This is homogeneous of degree $3$ in $a$, $b$, $c$, and symmetric. Moreover, it is $0$ for $a=0$. We conclude that it is divisible by $a$, and so also by $b$, $c$, and thus $ = k a b c$ for some constant $k$. Now take $a=b=c$, and see that $k = 3-27=-24$.