# If $2s=a+b+c$ , show that $16s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)=2b^2c^2+2c^2a^2+2a^2b^2-a^4-b^4-c^4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $2s=a+b+c$ , show that $\begin {align}16s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)&=2b^2c^2+2c^2a^2+2a^2b^2-a^4-b^4-c^4\end{align}$

$\begin{align} \implies 16s(s^2-as-bs+ab)(s-c)&=2b^2c^2+2c^2a^2-c^4-(a^4-2a^2b^2+b^4)\end{align}$

$\begin{align}16s(s^3-cs^2-as^2+acs-bs^2+bcs+abs-abc)&=c^2(2b^2+2a^2-c^2)-(a^2-b^2)^2\end{align}$

$\begin{align}16s[(s^3-as^2)+(abs-bs^2)+(acs-cs^2)+(bcs-abc)]&=c^2(2b^2+2a^2-c^2)-(a^2-b^2)^2\end{align}$

$\begin {align}16s[s^2(s-a)+bs(a-s)+cs(a-s)+bc(s-a)]&=c^2(2b^2+2a^2-c^2)-(a^2-b^2)^2\end {align}$

$\begin {align}8(a+b+c)[s^2(s-a)-bs(s-a)-cs(s-a)+bc(s-a)]&=c^2(2b^2+2a^2-c^2)-(a+b)^2(a-b)^2 \end {align}$

So if I keep going on the left hand side, I will get the original equation $16s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$, while on the right hand side this is the extent of what I can do. The problem is I feel I am no closer to making the left hand side having the same equation as the right hand side. I feel like the left hand side can be left alone as $16s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$, while I need to find a way to manipulate the right hand side to produce a $2s=a+b+c$ term somehow. But I can't see how to do that. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The same techniques from the other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4685979/if-2s-abc-show-that-s-a3s-b3s-c33abc-s3) work here, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

drop the $s$ as soon as possible. I am making everything become the difference of squares, as much as possible. At the very end we square a trinomial...

$$   LHS = 2s \; \;2(s-a) \;\;2(s-b) \;\; 2 (s-c)  $$
$$ LHS = (a+b+c) (-a+b+c)  (a-b+c)   (a+b-c)  $$
$$  (b+c +a) (b+c - a) \; \; (a+ (b-c))   (a-(b-c))  $$
$$  \left(  (b+c)^2 -a^2 \right)  \; \;   \left( a^2 - (b-c)^2  \right)  $$
getting there, give me a minute
$$  \left(b^2 + 2bc + c^2 - a^2 \right)        \left( a^2 - b^2 + 2bc - c^2\right)          $$

$$  \left( 2bc + (b^2 + c^2 - a^2)  \right)  \left( 2bc - (b^2 + c^2 - a^2)  \right)   $$

$$  LHS =   4 b^2 c^2 -  (b^2 + c^2 - a^2)^2  $$

need:
$$ (b^2 + c^2 - a^2)^2 = a^4 + b^4 + c^4 +2b^2 c^2 -2c^2 a^2 -2a^2b^2 $$

$$  LHS =   4 b^2 c^2    - a^4 - b^4 - c^4 -2b^2 c^2 +2c^2 a^2 +2a^2b^2 $$

$$  LHS =   2 b^2 c^2      +2c^2 a^2 +2a^2b^2    - a^4 - b^4 - c^4 $$

Answer (score 3):

You are basically trying to prove the famous Heron's formula. It's absolutely possible to just brute force expand and cancel term by term and I genuinely think beginners should do this. But a simpler way is to start from the end. Group the right-hand side as:

$$f(a) = -(a^4-2a^2(b^2+c^2) +(b^2+c^2)^2-4b^2c^2) = -((a^2-b^2-c^2)^2-(2bc)^2) = ...$$
and so on. But I do suggest  you solve it by brute force expanding once. It's a useful skill if you are learning olympiad geometry and inequalities.